# How protect my package or package body and put signiture of my export EXCEL file

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I used [this package](http://www.protalk.in/oracle/plsql-tips-package-for-exporting-data-to-excel/) to export my data from my data block to an excel file in ORACLE 6. Now I want to put my own document property on my Excel property.

First, Would you help me, what should I write when I create my Excel?

Second, I want to secure my codes(package and package body-sql files-) I mean nobody can see them,which way u suggesting to me?
(wrap,creating some thing like Object library)

third, when u working in a place that they pay u not so much do u put ur code free for them? or as much as they hire u they can use ur own package?

Comment: These are all very unrelated questions - please ask them separately. You won't be charged extra :)

Comment: Q1: more details required, i.e. what do you mean by "signature"?

Comment: Q2: you can wrap your packages so that others cannot easily view the package *body*, but the spec must always be visible.

Comment: Q3: this question would be more suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Signiture is signiture,go to Excel menu-> Prepare -> Properties

Comment: I want fill, Author,Title,Subject, keyword ,Category,Status

Comment: my company already wrap their code and also they know how to revert it! any other idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not find the property "signature" in the excel document properties. The namespace used by the pl/sql package to generate a excell file does not have a signature property.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms875215(v=EXCHG.65).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms875215%28v=EXCHG.65%29.aspx)

What version of excel are you using?

Are you really using oracle 6? The package you are using uses the UTL_File package which is intoduced in Oracle 7.

If someone hires you to do a job, regardeless of what they pay you, what you create is theirs. It's up to you to accept the job or not. A better appoarch is to work hard, show them your skills and after a while ask them for a raise.

EDIT 
: You'll have to change the package body of sql_to_excel and add the documentProperties you need.

```
        put_line(v_fileHandle,'<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>');
        put_line(v_fileHandle,' <o:DocumentProperties>');
        put_line(v_fileHandle,'  <o:LastAuthor>'||LOWER(USER)||'</o:LastAuthor>');
        put_line(v_fileHandle,'  <o:LastSaved>'||v_lastSaved||'</o:LastSaved>');
        put_line(v_fileHandle,'  <o:Version>10.6626</o:Version>');

        -- Put your props here
        put_line(v_fileHandle,'  <o:Author>10.6626</o:Author>');

        put_line(v_fileHandle,' </o:DocumentProperties>');
        put_line(v_fileHandle,' <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>');
        put_line(v_fileHandle,'  <o:DownloadComponents/>');
        put_line(v_fileHandle,' </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>');
        put_line(v_fileHandle,'</xml><![endif]-->');
```

Look at the link above to see the available properties.

Comment: Thanks man,really I change UTL_File to text_IO :D than it work well :D ;;) it think signature is equal document properties :D I will edit it.thanks man u are the best

Comment: Would you please tell me how you use the above link?I want to know it for more knowledge

Comment: I would like to train how to fishing not buy the fish ;)